# Equivalent histograms for x axes?

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting two histograms, one on top of the other, in order to compare distributions. How do I set the x-axes to be the same, meaning the range of x-values and the spacing between the ticks (bins) is the same for both histograms?

Answer (score 1):

You could also define same breaks for both. There are two ways to set breaks: a) You set it a single number defining the number of breaks. b) You set it a vector (for example `c(10,20,30)`), defining the exact break points. If you use the same vector for both histograms, the x-axes will be the same.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
mybreaks <- seq(from=0, to=100, by=5)
hist(rnorm(100, 20, 4), breaks = mybreaks)
hist(rnorm(100, 50, 4), breaks = mybreaks)
```

resulting for example in this:

[image: histograms]

Answer (score 0):

I realized how to do it: just adjust xlim = c(range) so that the two have the same range.